# Error in removing the first layer of keras model

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, tf.keras, keras-2

```
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.vgg19 import decode_predictions
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import time
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras import models, layers, Model, Input
import tensorflow as tf

model_2=keras.models.load_model('model_2.h5',compile=False)
model_2.summary()

predictions1= np.load('D:/predictions_result.npy')
def profiler(model, test_input):
 data_input=test_input
 for layer in model.layers:
    start = time.time()
    im_imput=keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=model.get_layer(layer.name).get_input_shape_at(0))
    im_out = layer(im_imput)
    new_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=im_imput,outputs=im_out)
    data_input = new_model.predict(data_input)
    end = time.time() - start
    print(end)
    result=1


profiler(model_2,predictions1)

tmp=np.zeros((1,224,224,64))

for i in range(0,1):
   tmp[i,:,:,:]=predictions1[i,:]

predictions2 = model_2.predict(tmp)
label_vgg19 = decode_predictions(predictions2)
print ('label_vgg19 =', label_vgg19)
```

When I try to run the above code I get below error. My question is how to remove the first layer of the model after loading. I initially split VGG model into sub-models and then load the submodel. I tried different approaches but none is working. Help is highly appreciated.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/40227422/PycharmProjects/model_partititon/model_2_sock.py", line 42, in <module>
  profiler(model_2,predictions1)
  File "C:/Users/40227422/PycharmProjects/model_partititon/model_2_sock.py", line 28, in the 
    profiler
  data_input = new_model.predict(data_input)
  File "C:\Users\40227422\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 332, in standardize_input_data
  ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))
  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array 
  with shape (224, 224, 64)
```

when I try to use kerassurgeon to delete a layer using below code I get error 
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

```
 from kerassurgeon import Surgeon
 surgeon = Surgeon(model_2)
 layer_1 = model_2.layers[0] # selecting 2nd layer

 surgeon.add_job('delete_layer', layer_1)
 new_model = surgeon.operate()
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue at the moment, have you figured what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to recreate the error you were facing. May be you can share the reproducible code. Below options I have tried to delete a layer and it worked.

```
from kerassurgeon.operations import delete_layer
# delete layer_1 from a model
model = delete_layer(model_2, layer_1)
```

OR

```
# delete layer_1 from a model
from kerassurgeon import Surgeon
surgeon = Surgeon(model_2)
surgeon.add_job('delete_layer', layer_1)
new_model = surgeon.operate()
```